# R count occurrences of firm per 2 and 3 years

Tags: r, count, data.table

I want to count the total number of firm per 2 and 3 years, the sampled data is:

```
# unbalanced data
library(data.table)
unbal <- data.frame(
  firm=c(rep('dell',9),rep('hp',5),rep('ibm',5),rep('asus',7)),
  year=c(2001,2001,2001,2003,2003,2003,2003,2004,2004,
         2003,3003,2004,2004,2004,
         2001,2002,2002,2002,2003,
         2003,2004,2004,2004,2004,2005,2005)
                    )
```

i know the easy way to count total per year by using data.table like

```
#repeated occurrence per year
test<-setDT(unbal)[, d12m:=.N, keyby=.(firm,year)]
```

but it makes me annoyed how to count the total occurrence per 2[d24m] and 3 years[d36m],because the data covers 15 years it would be very inefficient to recursively add year by year by hand.

*years are not successive, for example,dell has no data in 2002, so d24=d12 in this gap year case.

thx for any suggestion in advance.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. Do you want to count the number of observations in each range 2001-2002, 2002-2003, 2003-2004 etc?

Comment: right, i want to count the number of obs(firms) in each range(every 2 years 2001-2002... and every 3 years 2001-2003...).

Comment: You should show the desired output corresponding to this example.

Answer (score 0):

OK I think I have what you're looking for. It may not be the best approach, but I think you have to follow a process similar to this:

1) Your original data misses out years. To get consecutive groups we need to create a data frame which contains all years:

```
date_range<- data.frame(year=c(min(df$year):max(df$year))
```

*(note that your 'unbal' dataframe contains a typo - 3003 should be changed to 2003)*

and now also seems like a good time to specify the groupings for these years

```
date_range$twoyr<- rep(1:ceiling(nrow(date_range)/2),each=2)[1:nrow(date_range)]

date_range$threeyr<- rep(1:ceiling(nrow(date_range)/2),each=3)[1:nrow(date_range)]
```

*(the above code simply creates sequences repeating each level twice and three times respectively. 1:nrow(date_range) ensures that the vectors are the same size as the data we are appending to)*

2) create a new variable 'weight' which will allow us to add up the instances in unbal - the reason will become clear.

```
unbal$weight <- 1
```

3) create a cartesian product - all combinations of firms and dates *If you have a large dataset, this will take a while but is the only way I can think of to resolve the gaps in dates issue.*

```
cartes<-merge(date_range,firms)
```

4) use `dplyr` group_by and summarise functions to count those in 'every two years' and 'every three years' groups.

```
merge(cartes,unbal,by=c("year","firm"),all.x=T) %>% 
  group_by(twoyr,firm) %>%
  summarise(count=sum(weight)) %>% arrange(twoyr)

merge(cartes,unbal,by=c("year","firm"),all.x=T) %>% 
group_by(threeyr,firm) %>%
summarise(count=sum(weight)) %>% arrange(threeyr)
```

The variables 'twoyr' and 'threeyr' don't have very nice names but you should be able to rectify this further up. I'll change later perhaps.